# Grabbing the first frame of a video from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to get the first frame from the selected video in a `UIImagePickerController` to show in a `UIImageView`, but I do not know if it's possible. If it is, how would I do it?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 28):

You can do this in one of two ways. The first way is to use the `MPMoviePlayerController` to grab the thumbnail:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                       initWithContentURL:videoURL];
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:time
                     timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

This works, but `MPMoviePlayerController` is not a particularly lightweight object and not particularly fast grabbing thumbnails.

The preferred way is to use the new `AVAssetImageGenerator` in AVFoundation. This is fast, lightweight and more flexible than the old way. Here's a helper method that will return an autoreleased image from the video.

```
+ (UIImage *)thumbnailImageForVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL 
                             atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time 
{

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(asset);
    AVAssetImageGenerator *assetIG = 
                [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels;

    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = NULL;
    CFTimeInterval thumbnailImageTime = time;
    NSError *igError = nil;
    thumbnailImageRef = 
             [assetIG copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(thumbnailImageTime, 60)
                             actualTime:NULL
                                  error:&igError];

    if (!thumbnailImageRef)
        NSLog(@"thumbnailImageGenerationError %@", igError );

    UIImage *thumbnailImage = thumbnailImageRef 
                          ? [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef]
                          : nil;

    return thumbnailImage;
}
```

Asynchronous usage

```
- (void)thumbnailImageForVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time completion:(void (^)(UIImage *)) completion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
        NSParameterAssert(asset);
        AVAssetImageGenerator *assetIG =
        [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
        assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
        assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels;

        CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = NULL;
        CFTimeInterval thumbnailImageTime = time;
        NSError *igError = nil;
        thumbnailImageRef =
        [assetIG copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(thumbnailImageTime, 60)
                        actualTime:NULL
                             error:&igError];

        if (!thumbnailImageRef)
            NSLog(@"thumbnailImageGenerationError %@", igError );

        UIImage *thumbnailImage = thumbnailImageRef
        ? [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef]
        : nil;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(thumbnailImage);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: for other who tries to use this:
pay attention if the videoURL was created by fileURLWithPath or URLWithString (when you have the path in NSString*)

Comment: Just a question (and a heads up) - above method is sync yeah? Best to toss it into another thread.

Comment: You Even Packed it into a Public Class Method... Thanks ;-)

Comment: [assetIG copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(thumbnailImageTime, 60) <== why is 60?