# Extract frame from video in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to extract frames as UIImages from a video in Swift.  I found several Objective C solutions but I'm having trouble finding anything in Swift.  Assuming the following is correct can someone either help me to convert the following to Swift or give me their own take on how to do this?

Source:
[Grabbing the first frame of a video from UIImagePickerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518668/grabbing-the-first-frame-of-a-video-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
    
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(asset);
    AVAssetImageGenerator *assetIG =
    [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels;
    
    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = NULL;
    CFTimeInterval thumbnailImageTime = time;
    NSError *igError = nil;
    thumbnailImageRef =
    [assetIG copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(thumbnailImageTime, 60)
                    actualTime:NULL
                         error:&amp;igError];
    
    if (!thumbnailImageRef)
        NSLog(@"thumbnailImageGenerationError %@", igError );
    
    UIImage *image = thumbnailImageRef
    ? [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef]
    : nil;
    
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I never tried this for myselves, but I hope [this](https://objectivec2swift.com/) would help you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It actually did work.

```
func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

    let assetIG = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels

    let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let thumbnailImageRef: CGImage
    do {
        thumbnailImageRef = try assetIG.copyCGImage(at: cmTime, actualTime: nil)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImageRef)
}
```

But remember that this function is synchronous and it's better not to call it on the main queue.

You can do either this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let image = self.imageFromVideo(url: url, at: 0)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Or use [`generateCGImagesAsynchronously`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1388100-generatecgimagesasynchronously) instead of `copyCGImage`.

Comment: @Dmitry using this but image that i get is brighter than the video..can anyone help..???

Answer (score 6):

Here's a **SWIFT 5** alternative to Dmitry's solution, to not have to worry about what queue you're on:

```
public func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

        let assetIG = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGenerator.ApertureMode.encodedPixels

        let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 60)
        let thumbnailImageRef: CGImage
        do {
            thumbnailImageRef = try assetIG.copyCGImage(at: cmTime, actualTime: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return completion(nil)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImageRef))
        }
    }
}
```

Here's now to use it:

```
imageFromVideo(url: videoUrl, at: 0) { image in
   // Do something with the image here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of @Dmitry answer which uses Swift Concurrency (basically async/await) to eliminate completion handlers

### Solution for iOS 16 and newer:

```swift
// make sure to call this from background queue
func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval) async throws -> UIImage {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImageGenerator.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGenerator.ApertureMode.encodedPixels

    let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let thumbnailImage = try await assetImageGenerator.image(at: cmTime).image
    return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImage)
}
```

### Solution for iOS 15 and older:

```
func imageFromVideo(url: URL, at time: TimeInterval) async throws -> UIImage {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ continuation in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
            let assetIG = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetIG.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            assetIG.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGenerator.ApertureMode.encodedPixels

            let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale: 60)
            let thumbnailImageRef: CGImage
            do {
                thumbnailImageRef = try assetIG.copyCGImage(at: cmTime, actualTime: nil)
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                return
            }
            continuation.resume(returning: UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImageRef))
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
let vidUrl = <#your url#>
do {
    let firstFrame = try await imageFromVideo(url: vidUrl, at: 0)
    // do something with image
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

Or like this if you're in throwing function:

```
func someThrowingFunc() async throws {
    let vidUrl = <#your url#>
    let firstFrame = try await imageFromVideo(url: vidUrl, at: 0)
    // do something with image
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `copyCGImage(at:actualTime:)` which is deprecated, use `image(at:)` that is async alternative, which helps you avoid writing `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` block.

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I'll update the answer soon to use this approach

Comment: @Suprafen I added usage of the new method as an iOS 16+ solution(since the method is only available in iOS 16+), I think it's better to also keep the older solution, since iOS 15 isn't old enough yet (like iOS 10 now is (it isn't even supported by Xcode now)), some fellow developers might need it

Answer (score -2):

You can do this easily on iOS. Below is a code snippet on how to do so with Swift.

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video_name", withExtension: "mp4")
    let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: url!)
    
    let t1 = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 1)
    let t2 = CMTime(value: 4, timescale: 1)
    let t3 = CMTime(value: 8, timescale: 1)
    let timesArray = [
        NSValue(time: t1),
        NSValue(time: t2),
        NSValue(time: t3)
    ]
    
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: videoAsset)
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
    
    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: timesArray ) { requestedTime, image, actualTime, result, error in
        
       let img = UIImage(cgImage: image!)
       
    }
```

You can find the demo code [here](https://github.com/Ruchiram4/SwiftFrameExtractor) and the medium article [here](https://medium.com/@ruchiram4/swift-extract-frames-from-video-707ddca05674).