# Generating thumbnails for movies from iTunes file sharing data?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, itunes, file-sharing

i´m using the itunes file sharing feature to import customized data from the user.
I need to play videos when tapping on a customized UIButton. Therefore i want to know if its possible to set a thumbnail image from a video to each instance of MyButton.

I´ve played already with the MPMoviePlayerController and its "thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption" function. It works great after selecting and playing that one video. But i need to generate thumbnails for all videos before.

When syncing videos on any iOS device via itunes, apple generates thumbnails for the camera roll instantly. So thats the way i´m looking for.. Any ideas how apple is doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve got it. Using the AVFoundationFramework with "AVAssetImageGenerator" ;)
[Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)