# Create thumbnail from a video url in IPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, thumbnails

I am trying to acquire a thumbnail from a video url. The video is a stream (HLS) with the m3u8 format.
I've already tried requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes from the MPMoviePlayerController, but that didn't work. Does anyone have a solution for that problem? If so how'd you do it?

Comment: You can visit to the link given below. Very useful.
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetImageGenerator

Comment: Check it for once https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164607/3908884

Answer (score 48):

If you don't want to use `MPMoviePlayerController`, you can do this:

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:sourceURL];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC
```

Here's an example in Swift:

```
func thumbnail(sourceURL sourceURL:NSURL) -> UIImage {
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: sourceURL)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    let time = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 1)

    do {
        let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return UIImage(named: "some generic thumbnail")!
    }
}
```

I prefer using `AVAssetImageGenerator` over `MPMoviePlayerController` because it is thread-safe, and you can have more than one instantiated at a time.

Comment: The CGImageRef you get from -copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error: needs to be released with CGImageRelease();

Comment: Gives me the error AVErrorOperationNotSupportedForAsset . plz help

Comment: just as a side note... AV needs the AVFoundationFramework and CMTime needs CoreMediaFramework (had a little headache with this ones) cheers!

Comment: Good method but it can miss video orientation like in my case.

Comment: perfect...this is a good alternative for iOS 7 as thumbnailImageAtTime is now deprecated.

Comment: please give me suggestion here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617130/error-getting-same-video-thumbnail-image-every-time-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 25):

> Acquire a thumbnail from a video url.

```
    NSString *strVideoURL = @"http://www.xyzvideourl.com/samplevideourl";
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strVideoURL] ;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]autorelease];
    UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    player = nil;
```

Replace your video URL string with `strVideoURL`.
You will get thumbnail as a output from `video`.
And thumbnail is `UIImage` type data !

Comment: i am using this code for the thumbnail of video from the url of youtube  but it is not giving me the image.i am using to put the thumbnail in the table view so can you help me

Comment: I think you can't get the video from Youtube URL like this www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx

Comment: I'm using this url http://www.sciencentral.com/news/image_db/2024515/NNM2212_AntPower_MSTR.mov
I get nil thumbnail image. please help

Answer (score 9):

```
-(UIImage *)loadThumbNail:(NSURL *)urlVideo
{    
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:urlVideo options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"err==%@, imageRef==%@", err, imgRef);
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
}
```

Add `AVFoundation` framework in your project and don't forget to import `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`  and you have to pass the path of your video saved in document directory as a parameter and receive the image as `UIImage`.

Comment: I have not saved the video in Documents Directory, and I do not want to save. I want to generate image from URL. Is it possible ?

Comment: Hello @ArpitBParekh, It is not possible to generate thumbnail online i.e. without saving in document directory. Please accept my answer if it works for you :)

Comment: thanks for reply. But after searching I did it. Let me post the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343358/how-to-generate-the-thumbnail-of-video-url-flv-format I do not know, but it worked.

Comment: For few seconds UI stucks. But If Ic all the below code on NSTimer (Another thread) , ?Ui des not stuck.

Answer (score 4):

you can get the thumbnail from your video url with the use of below code

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]autorelease];
UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

Comment: Technically deprecated in iOS 7, but it still works, and I could never figure out how to use – requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption: properly

Comment: What is recommended to use in ios7?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is useful for someone else who faces the same problem. I needed an easy solution for creating a thumbnail for Images, PDFs and Videos. To solve that problem I've created the following Library (in Swift).

https://github.com/prine/ROThumbnailGenerator

The usage is very straightforward: 
var thumbnailImage = ROThumbnail.getThumbnail(url)

It has internally three different implementations and depending on the file extension it does create the thumbnail. You can easily add your own implementation if you need a thumbnail creator for another file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 Version :

```
func createThumbnailOfVideoFromFileURL(videoURL: String) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(1), 100)
    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
        return thumbnail
    } catch {
        // Set a default image if Image is not acquired
        return UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using hard code value 100 of preferredTimeScale?

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.0:

```
  func generateThumbnailForVideoAtURL(filePathLocal: NSString) -> UIImage? {
    let vidURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePathLocal as String)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: vidURL as URL)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    let timestamp = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60)

    do {
        let imageRef = try generator.copyCGImage(at: timestamp, actualTime: nil)
        let frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
        return frameImg
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Image generation failed with error ::\(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 5** you can get it this way:

First `import AVKit or AVFoundation` to `ViewController`

```
import AVKit
```

**Code:**

```
// Get Thumbnail Image from URL
private func getThumbnailFromUrl(_ url: String?, _ completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url ?? "") else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

        let time = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
        do {
            let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
            completion(thumbnail)
        } catch {
            print("Error :: ", error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@IBOutlet weak imgThumbnail: ImageView!
```

and then call `getThumbnailFromUrl` method and pass `URL` as a `Sting`

```
self.getThumbnailFromUrl(videoURL) { [weak self] (img) in

    guard let `self` = self else { return }

    if let img = img {
        self.imgThumbnail.image = img
    }
}
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 code with AVAssetImageGenerator:

```
func thumbnailImageForVideo(url:NSURL) -> UIImage?
{
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    var time = asset.duration
    //If possible - take not the first frame (it could be completely black or white on camara's videos)
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    do {
        let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```