# How to play recored video output url in the table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, avcapturesession

I have a `CollectionView` with images and in the next `ViewController` I  am recording a video using Av captured sessions and i am saving it in to the mobile document directory,Then i am coming back to the collection and i am reloading the collection view now i  want the recored video in the collection view cell with out  using any api.

I used the below code to save the recored video in the directory

```
'- (void)saveRecordedFile:(NSURL *)recordedFile {



dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                     completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



             NSString *title;
             NSString *message;

             if (error != nil) {

                 title = @"Failed to save video";
                 message = [error localizedDescription];
             }
             else {
                 title = @"Saved!";
                 message = nil;
             }

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                             message:message
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];


             UIStoryboard *storybord=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

             shareViewController   *shareview=[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"share"];
             [self presentViewController:shareview animated:YES completion:nil];



         });
     }];
});
```

can any body help out to solve this problem.solution view code is appreciated.  i recored video by referring this  https://github.com/shu223/SlowMotionVideoRecorder

Comment: @Suraj sukale  can you give any solution

Comment: You do it in the "cellForItemsAtIndex" method. Dequeue video cell for video parse item.

Comment: can you suggest me some link or some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can achieve it by getting the center frame of the video which you have stored in the document directory.

2) You can store the center frame image of the video to document directory so that you don't have to generate everytime.

3) Display video thumbnail inside collectionview.

Refer this link for get frame of the video :

[Create thumbnail from a video url in IPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501413/create-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-iphone-sdk)

**EDIT:**

```
 NSString *videoPath = [videoURL path];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView]; [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: I have already saved the image in the document directory,i am finding the video in the device i want that video to pass from 2nd vc to 1st vc i which i nave collection view

Comment: Create one property inside 1st vc of type NSString which store the video path. When you pass from 2nd vc at that time set the value in that property.

Comment: shareview.videoPath = yourvideoPath;

Comment: videoPath is the property which you have to create in shareviewcontroller

Comment: my path is in url formate and i converted it in to string in that view controller it self and i am taking another string in the share view controller and i am assigning the  output string url like this   NSString *videostring=[recordedFile absoluteString];
  NSLog(@"%@",videostring);
 UIStoryboard *storybord=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
      shareViewController   *shareview=[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"share"];
 [self presentViewController:shareview animated:YES completion:nil];
   shareview.videooutputstring=videostring;

Comment: You getting video ?

Comment: You can also create NSURL type property also.

Comment: At the end you need proper path from where you can get the video

Comment: when print the recordedfile output i am getting the path and the path is file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5421D684-D466-44F1-AEF5-7390598B5647/Documents/2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV.

Comment: how to create nsurl type property

Comment: NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: recordedfile];

Comment: videourl from your path

Comment: after that what should i do

Comment: What you want to display in collectionview ? image or video?

Comment: You have to display video image not video inside collectionview.

Comment: once you tap on that then you can do whatever you want to do with that URL.

Comment: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *' parameter of type 'NSString * _Nonnull' warning it is showing  when i do this  
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: recordedfile];

Comment: You have to set property type to NSURL which you have set NSString.

Comment: can you please send it as a code such that i can understand easily

Comment: when i log the NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: recordedfile];,videouel it is showing ile:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B23DB5D5-8503-4F15-A595-88F689DA6646/Documents/2016-08-03-12-34-49-0.MOV -- file:///

Comment: Did you get any problem if file:/// is there?

Comment: i ma getting path like this file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE968CDC-61B1-4AB2-959E-E285B364431F/Documents/2016-08-03-16-19-38-0.MOV -- file:///   and i am playing the video i am writing this code  //    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
      [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];

       [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];  any mistake

Comment: I have modified your code. Please try it. Let me know working or not.

Comment: Have you checked video is there in the document directory?

Comment: Let me know what you are getting in videoPath. NSString *videoPath = [videoURL path];

Comment: it is showing the video playing view and it is not playing,play button is nott highlighted and the view is not dismissing

Comment: now the path is like this /file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9729492D-AB8E-4001-AD05-8159C3E63314/Documents/2016-08-03-17-01-15-0.MOV  this is the correct path,video have to play now but video playing view is appearing but is not playing and it is not dismissing.

Comment: put this static path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9729492D-AB8E-4001-AD05-8159C3E633‌​14/Documents/2016-08-03-17-01-15-0.MOV

Comment: and check is it playing or not. I don't know what you have done.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9729492D-AB8E-4001-AD05-8159C3E633‌​14/D‌​ocuments/2016-08-03-17-01-15-0.MOV"]]; add static path like this it is showing same result

Comment: Hi good morning bro.i user the code which is given in the below link please go through that please https://github.com/shu223/SlowMotionVideoRecorder