# How to generate thumbnail from video stream?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am wondering how I can get `UIImage` from video stream?

What I have done :

First I run stream:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: sourceURL)
player.play()
```

Then I check if `asset` from `AVPlayer` is not empty.

```
if let asset = player.currentItem?.asset {
   let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
   imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = CMTimeMake(1, 15)
   imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = CMTimeMake(1, 15)
   let time = CMTimeMake(1, 1)
   let imageRef = try! imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
   return UIImage(cgImage:imageRef)
}
```

I am using `try!` for test purposes and I know that I am not handling exceptions.

But I receive error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170654250 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12782 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12782),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Also I try this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501413/create-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-iphone-sdk).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create thumbnail from a video url in IPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501413/create-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: @AhmadF problem is video is stream url.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk could you find a solution or something about that? I facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you remove the 
 `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` and `requestedTimeToleranceAfter` you will have no problems. Or change their property to `kCMTimeZero`
I would also suggest adding the following line

```
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
```

Comment: Thx for the response. But their is no luck with you're suggestion.

Comment: Just to be sure, your video is loading correctly, despite this error, right?

Comment: Yes it is possible just to play video.

Comment: Did you leave out any other maybe relevant code? Maybe a threading issue? This should be an open and shut case with the code provided. :/