# how to set thumbnail image of video?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom button in my application on click of which I present a UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera to take a video.

Now, after capturing the video I want to set a thumbnail of it to this custom button.

How to take 1st frame of that video to set thumbnail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer the following links. You can get some ideas regarding creating thumbnails for videos.

1. [Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)
2. stackoverflow.com/questions/1259316/iphone-sdk-3-0-video-thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
NSString *videoLink=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];   
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:(NSURL*)videoLink];
UIImage *imageSel = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[player stop];
[player release];
```