# How to show the first frame of video as a Thumbnail image in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am creating an iPhone app in which user will be able to capture the video and when he will done with that, the first frame of that video should be shown as a thumbnail image.
How can I show that image, I mean how can I extract the first frame of video?
Thanks-

Comment: what method are you using to capture the video?

Comment: do some search man.. the very first option on google gives you this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4330647/919545

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava I did searching but I didn't get this link. May be I was using the different key words for searching! Well Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are two options:-

1) Using the MPMoviePlayerController.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                       initWithContentURL:videoURL];
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:time
                     timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

2) Using AVURLAsset

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
[asset release];
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    thumbImg=[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] retain];
    [generator release];
};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: Thanks Anil, Let me try these methods and I will get back to you with response.

Comment: The first option using MPMoviePlayerController worked great for me.

Comment: `[thumbnailImageAtItem:timeOption:]` was deprecated with the release of iOS7. `[requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption]` is the new API call expecting an NSArray of NSNumber objects containing the times at which to capture the thumbnail images.