# Grabbing First Frame of a Video - Thumbnail Resolution - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, video, thumbnails

I want to display the (static) first frame of a video in my app as a preview.

I have read through this thread and understand that I could use a thumbnail :

[Getting a thumbnail from a video url or data in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)

I have two questions :

1) What is the resolution of the thumbnail ? I am looking to make the preview a 4:3 format and wonder if the image will end up looking blurry if enlarged.

2) Does the resolution of the thumbnail differ for iPhone / iPad ?

3) Is there a better way to grab and display the first frame of a video ?

Thank you.

Comment: image.size will get you the size of the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following code may helping to you

```
NSString *str = [[self.vedioArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"vName"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str] ;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]autorelease];
  UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    player = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks Neon - this may be a stupid question, but is it possible to use that framework in an existing project ? It assumes you are going to create a new project.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController ` is deprecated, so `AVPlayerViewController ` should be used.