# Lazyloading for videos coming from urls iphone

Tags: iphone, video, lazy-loading

I have to show the thumbnails from the video on the table cells.

The video is coming from the URL, and I need to lazy load the images captured from the iPhone.

Comment: That's nice. [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330647/251513) SO answer, or use [thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:) method of [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
For the lazy loading on the cells, you could load the thumbnail in the [willDisplayCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) callback of [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) so you'll load/display the thumbnail once the cell is created (you can see a similar behavior in the AppStore App). Remember also that you have to download your videos in asynchronous way in order to not block the main thread.