# How to take the screenshot when playing the MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I take screenshot when playing the video in MPMoviePlayer? I am using the below code for take screenshot but the player screen is black color.
1)

```
- (UIImage*)captureScreenshot:(UIView *)view {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);
        return viewImage;
    }
```

2) `CGImageRef originalImage = UIGetScreenImage();`

This is apple banned.

Please give any other way to get screenshot from the movie player. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat hacktastic, but you could take a screenshot, grab a thumbnail from the movie player (e.g. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)) and overlay the second on the first.