# show video time length in thumbnail image in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image, video

In my app, I recorded the video & also displaying the thumbnail Image in iphone. It all works fine.

But my thumbnail image is not shows the video time length.

I got the code from following link:

[ThumbNail Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)

```
//my code

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

        UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

**How can i solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

   UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showDuration:) name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:player];


-(void)showDuration:(NSNotification*)notif
 {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = (MPMoviePlayerController*)[notif object];
NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", player.duration);
  }
```

Comment: use notfication center with MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification

Comment: NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

        UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showDuration:) name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:player];

Comment: -(void)showDuration:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = (MPMoviePlayerController*)[notif object];
    NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", player.duration);
}