# thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

I have the code below:

```m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
self.selectedMessage = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *fileType = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"fileType"];
if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImage" sender:self];

} else {

    // File type is video
    PFFile *videoFile = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:videoFile.url];
    self.moviePlayer.contentURL = fileUrl;
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    // Add it to the view controller so we can see it
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

On the line that says:

```m
[self.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

it gives me the error:

`thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

If anyone could help fix this problem, it would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [thumbnailImageAtTime: now deprecated - What's the alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105721/thumbnailimageattime-now-deprecated-whats-the-alternative)

Answer (score 3):

Please see my answer to this same issue here [ThumbnailImageAtTime Deprecated - What's the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105721/thumbnailimageattime-now-deprecated-whats-the-alternative/19126159#19126159)

```m
AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:partOneUrl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
[_firstImage setImage:one];
_firstImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Within header file, please import

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

It works perfect and I've been able to call it from viewDidLoad, which was quicker than calling the deprecated thumbNailImageAtTime: from the viewDidAppear.

Hope this helps anyone else who had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```m
AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:partOneUrl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
[_firstImage setImage:one];
_firstImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Add `AVFoundation` and `CoreMedia` framework

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
```

Comment: I get confused with the time variable, how do I get a image at 1 sec in to the video, and how do I get an image 2 seconds in?