# How do I get NSArray of images from a video? Vice-versa is possible

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, video

It is possible that I can play video from `NSArray` of images. But how can I get `NSArray` of images from a video?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to make image from Video and later you can save those image in a array

```
UIImage *singleFrameImage = [self.theMoviePlayer 
                              thumbnailImageAtTime:i 
                                        timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

Comment: It is working but "thumbnailImageAtTime: timeOption:" is deprecated from iOS 7. Thanks for the answer BTW.

Comment: I found this: [thumbnailImageAtTime: now deprecated - What's the alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105721/thumbnailimageattime-now-deprecated-whats-the-alternative) and this article: [Getting thumbnail from video url or data](http://www.amaniphoneblog.com/2015/05/getting-thumbnail-from-video-url-or-data-in-IOS.html).

Answer (score 0):

To **get a image from your video** use this sample.

First import `AVFoundation`

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Create the `NSURL` from your video.

```
NSString *videoUrl = @"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];
```

Prepare the `asset`.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
```

Select the time to cut: e.g. In second `2` for `1` second.

```
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(2, 1);
```

Get the `ImageRefference` and the `Thumbnail`.

```
NSError *error = nil;
CGImageRef imageRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];

UIImage *thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Set your image to some `UIImageView` .

```
[self.imageView setImage:thumbnail];
```

[The Sample shows this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inuxz.png)

Comment: It's not working if the video is in app bundle or in document directory. I am getting this error while getting imageRef - "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x124722f90 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12433 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12433), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}"

Comment: This is a new problem. You should search how create the `NSURL` for local files.