# Display ViewController after didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo - Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a `ViewController` that opens the camera once user is put unto that `ViewController`  My issue is that once the user creates a video and clicks `use`.  The `ViewController` closes because, `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
 is called.  But if I remove this from the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` The captured video will just stay at that pending `Container` that shows to recapture or use or play back.  What I am mean is, I want the user to stay at that ViewController but minimize that `Video` container and show the `ViewController`.  The `ViewController` will have input boxes to enter information into for that captured video before I send it to my server for uploading.

Suggestions thoughts?

Comment: You can dismiss the view controller and present another view controller to the user with input boxes and the thumbnail of the video.

Comment: @Kudocc could you give me an example of making the thumbnail?

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340737/getting-thumbnail-from-movie)