# I want to display a videothumbnail image of a video from url in my uiimageview for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, video-thumbnails

Is it possible to get the first image frame of a video and display it in uiimageview . My video is saved in the server. i need to call the url to play the video

Answer (score 3):

An example:

```
NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
[YourImageView setImage:img];
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: the question explicitly says that the video is on the server (remote).. thus fileURLWithPath which are used for filesystem url are not correct

Comment: Hi lakesh, Actually when i scroll the Table view then the table view hangs & after some time they scroll.....

Comment: @Gurpreet My view stucks, when I use such method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343358/how-to-generate-the-thumbnail-of-video-url-flv-format?rq=1 this worked for me. Just I have to call the method after some time interval so UI does not freeze.

Answer (score 3):

I use this method to do the same

```
/**
 *  This method retunrs a thumbnail of a Video file
 */

+ (UIImage *)generateThumbnailIconForVideoFileWith:(NSURL *)contentURL WithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIImage *theImage = nil;
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:contentURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.maximumSize=size;
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(100,100); //change whatever you want here.
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef] ;
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
    return theImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `MPMoviePlayerController` like bellow..

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:yourVideoURL];
UIImage *videoThumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[player stop];
```

Also see another answer with `AVURLAsset` from this link [getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)