# retrieved videos as PFFile in Uiimage

Tags: parse-platform, uiimage, pffile

I'm trying to put retrieved videos from Parse in UIimage and i need help of that. 
i retrieved videos as a PFFile .
here is my code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell :mineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mineCell")as! mineCell

    cell.usernameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

    videoFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (videoData :NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if videoData != nil{
        let video = UIImage(data: videoData!)
            cell.videoView.image = video
            println("it should the video load in the UImage ")
        }
        else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
    return cell
```

Comment: Good. Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: Thanks for replaying @planetmaker ,The actual problem is the video did't load in the uiimage, is there another way to load it in

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't put video data into a UIImage.

You need to get a UIImage as a thumbnail for the video, [which has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962473/i-want-to-display-a-videothumbnail-image-of-a-video-from-url-in-my-uiimageview-f).

From there, playing a video from a PFFile can be accomplished with the following steps

```
// Load yourObject which has the video (PFFile)
var fileURL = NSURL(string: yourObject.video.url!)
var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: fileURL)
self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayer)
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.play()
```