# How to generate video thumbnail using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to get the thumbnail of the video using the following code.

```
 UIImage *thumbnail = [mp thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

But i want to know how can i get the thumbnail of the video without sending any request to the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting thumbnail from a video url or data in IPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk)