# Get Image from Selected Video UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

How can i retrieve or make a thumbnail image of the selected video to be used in a another view controller after the video has been selected by user?

```
 func imagePickerController1(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        // 1
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
        // 2
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            // 3
            if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
                let moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)
                self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayer)
            }

        }

        let destination = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FinializePost")
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destination, animated: true);
    }
```

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347562/getting-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-or-data-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
 let URL_originalvideo = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]

    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(URL_originalvideo) as AVAsset
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset);
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1)

    var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
    var error : NSError?
    let myImage = imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: &actualTime, error: &error)
```

myImage is what you need.