# Exporting image sequence from video in swift

Tags: swift, image, video, avfoundation, cmtime

I have the below code to export a video (60fps) to an image sequence.
However, despite loads of stackoverflow examples, I seem to not master properly the CMTime, as images 1-30 are the same, then 31-90 are the same, then 91-130, 131-150... like if the generated sequence would be stop motion.

```swift
var seq=0
let duration:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
let fps = tracks.first!.nominalFrameRate

for index:Float64 in stride(from: 0, to: duration, by: Double(1/fps)) {
    let time:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(index, preferredTimescale:Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    var image:CGImage
    do {
        try image = generator.copyCGImage(at:time, actualTime:nil)
        let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: image)
        let data = bitmapRep.representation(using: .jpeg, properties: [:])
        let oneimagepath=newpath.appendingPathComponent("Sequence.\(String(format: "%04d", seq)).jpg")
        seq = seq+1
        try data?.write(to: oneimagepath, options: .atomicWrite)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Is the issue into my CMTime, or somewhere else ? It's like if it would convert my decimal time to an int.

Comment: What does "to export a video (60fps) to an image sequence" mean?  You mean, you want to save a series of movie frames to a disk or something as images?  It looks like that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes that’s correct. Movie of 10 secs @ 60 fps would give me 600 Jpeg images on disk

Comment: It's probably the `AVAssetImageGenerator`s time tolerance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541651/22147

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot !! You may want to post it as answer so I can properly rate it.